# Grid gap being added to the one end of the grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Im not sure why but my grid gap is being added to the right side of my grid , twice. This shouldnt be the classic using % problem as im using fr and in the developer tools i can see two grid gaps being added, Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
    .Portfolio .wrapper{
    grid-gap:10px;
    padding:40px 0px;
    width: 95%;
    margin: auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5,1fr) ;
    grid-auto-rows: 200px;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "img-30 img-30 img-30 img-31 img-31"
        "img-30 img-30 img-30 img-31 img-31"
        "img-35 img-35 img-34 img-34 img-34"
        "img-35 img-35 img-34 img-34 img-34"
        "img-36 img-36 img-36 img-32 img-32"
        "img-36 img-36 img-36 img-32 img-32"

;
}
.Portfolio .wrapper >*{
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.Portfolio .wrapper .img-30{
    background-image: url("Images/30.jpg");
    grid-area: img-30;

} 
.Portfolio .wrapper .img-31{
    background-image: url("Images/31.jpg");
    grid-area: img-31;

} 
.Portfolio .wrapper .img-32{
    background-image: url("Images/32.jpg");
    grid-area: img-32;
} 
.Portfolio .wrapper .img-33{
    background-image: url("Images/33.jpg");
    grid-area: img-33;
} 
.Portfolio .wrapper .img-34{
    background-image: url("Images/34.jpg");
    grid-area: img-34;
} 
.Portfolio .wrapper .img-35{
    background-image: url("Images/35.jpg");
    grid-area: img-35;
    background-color: red;
} 
.Portfolio .wrapper .img-36{
    background-image: url("Images/36.jpg");
    grid-area: img-36;
} 


<main class="Portfolio">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="img-30"></div>
        <div class="img-31"></div>
        <div class="img-32"></div>
        <div class="img-33"></div>
        <div class="img-34"></div>
        <div class="img-35"></div>
        <div class="img-36"></div>
    </div>
```

Here is my HTML - NOTE!! it says repeat(3,1fr) but its actually repeat(5,1fr)

Comment: You have set 3 columns but 5 in the areas

Comment: add your HTML code if you still need help.

Comment: Apologies, The code is actually repeat(5,1fr) so there are are 5 columns

Comment: @DamjanOstrelic Added my html

Comment: @SidTurner I've added an answer, let me know if it helps or you need further help with it.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't used `.img-33` in your `grid-template-areas:`. The following code works for me:

CSS:

```
    .Portfolio .wrapper{
    grid-gap:10px;
    padding:40px 0px;
    width: 95%;
    margin: auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5,1fr) ;
    grid-auto-rows: 200px;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "img-30 img-30 img-30 img-31 img-31"
        "img-30 img-30 img-30 img-31 img-31"
        "img-35 img-35 img-34 img-34 img-34"
        "img-35 img-35 img-34 img-34 img-34"
        "img-36 img-36 img-36 img-32 img-32"
        "img-36 img-36 img-36 img-32 img-32"
        "img-33 img-33 img-33 img-33 img-33";
}
.Portfolio .wrapper > * {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.Portfolio .wrapper .img-30{
    background: blue;
    grid-area: img-30;

} 
.Portfolio .wrapper .img-31{
    background: green;
    grid-area: img-31;

} 
.Portfolio .wrapper .img-32{
    background: cyan;
    grid-area: img-32;
} 
.Portfolio .wrapper .img-33{
    background: purple;
    grid-area: img-33;
} 
.Portfolio .wrapper .img-34{
    background: pink;
    grid-area: img-34;
} 
.Portfolio .wrapper .img-35{
    background: orange;
    grid-area: img-35;
    background-color: red;
} 
.Portfolio .wrapper .img-36{
    background: yellow;
    grid-area: img-36;
}
```

HTML:

```
<main class="Portfolio">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="img-30">30</div>
        <div class="img-31">31</div>
        <div class="img-32">32</div>
        <div class="img-33">33</div>
        <div class="img-34">34</div>
        <div class="img-35">35</div>
        <div class="img-36">36</div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Check this demo: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c19o56n4/1/).